# how to align column title and content in knitr

Tags: alignment, knitr, kableextra

Just trying to align title of a column to its contents in knitr. what is the function? When I use `align = 'c'` or `position = 'c'`, it gives me an error:

> unused argument (align = "c").

This is my code:

```
DF_3 <-structure(list(. = structure(c(11L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 13L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 12L, 3L, 1L, 10L, 9L),
                                    .Label = c("B", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "H", "H", "I", "J", "M", "N", "V"), class = "f"),
                      HEV.pos = structure(c(3L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 5L),
                                          .Label = c("1 (2)", "15", "16", "19", "20", "24", "26", "4 (7)", "6 (11)", "7 (13)"), class = "factor"),
                      HEV.neg = structure(c(9L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 10L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 5L),
                                          .Label = c("10 (28)", "12 ", "15 ", "17", "18 ", "19 ", "2 ", "4", "7", "9"), class = "factor")),
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L)) 


library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)

kable(DF_3, format = "html") %>% 
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped") %>%
  row_spec(1, bold = T) %>% 
  row_spec(6, bold = T) %>%
  column_spec(1, bold = T)
```

Comment: I assume you are referring to the kable function? Can you provide a minimal example of the problem that we can reproduce? Finally, what is the output format of the table, html or PDF?

Comment: Hello Mikey. Yes, this is kable function. and the output is a table. The numbers in my table stick to the left side, and as I have long title, the aesthetics looks a bit weird. kable(DF_3) %>%          kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped") %>% row_spec(1, bold = T) %>% row_spec(6, bold = T) %>% column_spec(1, bold = T) %>% add_header_above(c("." = 1, "Males" = 3, "Females" = 3))  Thanks.

Comment: I have added the above code to the question. However, it is still not a minimal example as we do not have access to your `DF_3`.  Can you add the output of `dput(DF_3)` to your question?

Comment: structure(list(. = structure(c(11L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 13L, 5L, 4L, 
2L, 12L, 3L, 1L, 10L, 9L), .Label = c("B", "D", 
"E", "F", "G", "H", "H", "H", "I", "J", "M", "N", "V"), class = "f"), HEV.pos = structure(c(3L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 7L,    3L, 8L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("1 (2)", "15", "16",     "19", "20", "24", "26", "4 (7)", "6 (11)",  "7 (13)"), class = "factor"), HEV.neg = structure(c(9L, 2L,  7L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 10L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("10 (28)",  "12 ", "15 ", "17", "18 ", "19 ", "2 ", "4", "7", "9"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not clear to see where you were trying to use the `align` argument. However, it has to be provided to the `kable` function. The function documentation stats:

> *Column alignment: a character vector consisting of 'l' (left), 'c' (center) and/or 'r' (right). By default or if align = NULL, numeric columns are right-aligned, and other columns are left-aligned. If length(align) == 1L, the string will be expanded to a vector of individual letters, e.g. 'clc' becomes c('c', 'l', 'c'), unless the output format is LaTeX.

As some examples:

```
knitr::kable(mtcars[1:5, 1:5], caption = "Left Aligned")
```

[image]

```
knitr::kable(mtcars[1:5, 1:5], align = "c", caption = "Center Aligned")
```

[image]

```
knitr::kable(mtcars[1:5, 1:5], align = c("c", "l", "r", "c", "c"), caption = "Mixed Aligned")
```

[image]

Comment: When I tried: caption = "Center Aligned". I got:                                 Error in htmlTable_styling(kable_input, bootstrap_options = bootstrap_options,  : 
  unused argument (caption = "Center Aligned")

Comment: You seem to be putting the `knitr::kable` commands into the `kable_styling` function? Are you copying the format of my examples?

Comment: Finally I got it done. What I had to do is just add align = "c", caption = "Center Aligned" together after the file name. Many thanks.

Comment: Great, can you please upvote the answer and mark as accepted if you are happy :)? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: In my column titles if I have more than I word, it gives me a period (.) rather than a space between the words. How can I change that? Thanks.

Comment: Look at the function documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/knitr/versions/1.20/topics/kable . You can specify the 'col.names'